# Selenium save file to current working directory

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a website which I'm querying after solving a `CAPTCHA`.
After solving the `CAPTCHA` my query downloads a `PDF` file. My issue is that I cannot get `FireFox` to download the file automatically to the current working directory without user interaction.

I also cannot figure out how to determine if the file already exists, which would prompt my code to display either a dialog or a message.

Here's my current code, which does everything correctly until the file download popup.

```py
import os
import logging
import argparse
import requests
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import exceptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

logger = logging.getLogger('tst-log-query')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)-5.5s - %(message)s', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(
    'tst-log-query.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

mainurl = "https://cndt-certidao.tst.jus.br/inicio.faces"
ckey = "f1a382ddd51949057324a7fc7c8ccf8a"


def solver(captcha):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        print("[*] - Please wait while CAPTCHA is solved ")
        cdata1 = {
            "clientKey": ckey,
            "task": {
                "type": "ImageToTextTask",
                "body": captcha
            }
        }
        cdata2 = {
            "clientKey": ckey
        }
        while True:
            try:
                r = req.post(
                    'https://api.anti-captcha.com/createTask', json=cdata1)
                cdata2['taskId'] = r.json()['taskId']
                break
            except KeyError:
                logger.debug(r.json()["errorDescription"])
                continue

        while True:
            sleep(5)
            logger.info("Slept 5 Seconds!")
            fr = req.post(
                'https://api.anti-captcha.com/getTaskResult', json=cdata2)
            status = fr.json()
            logger.debug("Status: {}".format(status["status"]))
            if status['status'] == "ready":
                cap = status['solution']['text']
                print("[*] - CAPTCHA Solved!")
                return cap
            else:
                continue


def main(pat):

    # saving to current working directory
    options = Options()
    options.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
    options.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
    options.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
    options.set_preference(
        'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'pdf')
    #__________________________#

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    print(f"Checking (CNPJ/CPF)# {pat}")
    while True:
        try:
            driver.get(mainurl)
            waiter = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
            waiter.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value=Regularização]"))
            ).click()
            waiter.until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#consultarRegularizacaoForm\:cpfCnpj"))
            ).send_keys(pat)

            cap = waiter.until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[src^=data]"))).get_attribute('src').split(',', 1)[1]
            break
        except exceptions.TimeoutException:
            logger.error('[*] - Unable to found elements, Refreshing Request.')
            continue
    capso = solver(cap)
    if capso:
        driver.find_element(By.ID, 'idCaptcha').send_keys(capso)
        driver.find_element(
            By.ID, 'consultarRegularizacaoForm:btnEmitirCertidao').click()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Download PDF File!')
    parser.add_argument(
        'pattern', metavar="(CNPJ/CPF) Number", help="(CNPJ/CPF) Number", type=str)
    try:
        main(parser.parse_args().pattern)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit("Good Bye!")
```

Usage: `python script.py 15436940000103`

Comment: Would the chrome webdriver alternative work?

Comment: @SiddharthaDutta why not!

Comment: Do you have some other example that does not involve captcha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.set_preference(
        "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Solved using the previous code.